# Deriving the Force on an ion in the Classical Harmonic Crystal

Tags: forces, potential, equilibrium

I was following Solid State Physics by Ashcroft and Memrmin and their introduction to the Classical Theory of the Harmonic Crystal. (Chapter 22)

If there are a large number of ions in a straight line, we can pick the nth ion oscillating about an equilibrium position na. It has neighbours at (n+1)a and (n-1)a. If only neighbouring ions can interact the potential energy of the entire crystal is:

U = (1/2)K*[u(na)-u([n+1]a)]^2 - summed over all values of n.

K is the potential energy between both the ions if they were at their equilibrium positions.

The book goes onto explain that the force is then:

-dU/du(an) = K[2u(an) - u([n-1]a) - u([n+1]a)].

I have tried but I can not derive this equation when differentiating U with respect to u(an). 
Namely, I struggle when it comes to differentiating u([n+1]a) with respect to u(an). Also how do you get u([n-1]a)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are overthinking the derivative part.  Consider that you know a set of discrete points (x,y).  How would you calculate, not knowing the form of y = f(x), the derivatives?

Comment: I would try and calculate (y1 - y2)/(x1 - x2)

Comment: And the second derivative?

Comment: if i have y0, y1, y2 in a line something like: ((y1-y0)-(y2-y1))/dx

Comment: which is (2y1 - y0 - y1)/dx... oh this looks really familliar

Comment: which then becomes 2*y1-y0-y2, which then looks a lot like...

Comment: Bingo. I think you've got it now...

Comment: Thanks alot for your help. I should have taken things to basics